# CSS for tr in table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is it possible to change backroung color to specific tr in a table?
How can i make so that each tr from id=1 to id=2 is blue, id=2 to id=3 red etc..

I have this code:

```
<tbody>
<tr id="1"></tr>   <-- Blue
<tr></tr>          <-- Blue
<tr></tr>          <-- Blue
<tr id="2"></tr>   <-- Red
<tr></tr>          <-- Red
<tr id="3"></tr>   <-- Green
<tr></tr>          <-- Green
<tr></tr>          <-- Green
<tr></tr>          <-- Green
</tbody>
```

Comment: Please post what you've tried.

Comment: You just need to use sibling CSS selector

Comment: I could not find any information about this, so i just need some advise where to start.

Comment: just google for what @A.Wolff has suggested you and you are ok.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```css
[id="1"], [id="1"] ~ tr {
  background-color: blue;
}
[id="2"], [id="2"] ~ tr {
  background-color: red;
}
[id="3"], [id="3"] ~ tr {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tbody>
<tr id="1"><td>foo</td></tr>
<tr><td>foo</td></tr>
<tr><td>foo</td></tr>
<tr id="2"><td>foo</td></tr>
<tr><td>foo</td></tr>
<tr id="3"><td>foo</td></tr>
<tr><td>foo</td></tr>
<tr><td>foo</td></tr>
<tr><td>foo</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You should include element itself: `[id="1"], [id="1"] ~ tr {...}`

Comment: Exellent! Thank you!! Is it possible to make that every even ID is red and every odd number is blue?

Comment: @StefanTrailovic you can use `:nth-child(even)` and `:nth-child(odd)`

Comment: @jcubic in the above code, some styles are overwritten by the previous ones . for exampe the 3rd box ( from the top ) should be red , because it has `#2`, same with the 6th box which should be green but it's red.  but eitherway , nice solution :)

Comment: @jcubic Thank you agian for the comment. But i can't get the 2 codes to work together. Either i get the [id="3"] ~ tr or :nth-child(even). How should i combine them? I tried [id="1"], [id="1"]:nth-child(odd) ~ tr and [id="2"], [id="2"]:nth-child(even).

Comment: @StefanTrailovic I think that :nth-child is applied fist to original elements and then the [id="2"] select those elements that also have id="2", so you can't combine them to have even or odd of the class, but you can ask another question to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

Look up CSS nth-child
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp

For example:

```
tr:nth-child(5n+3) {background-color:red}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or Css Class selector can aldo be alternative for this

```css
.blue{
background-color:blue;
color:white
}
.red{
background-color:red;
color:white
}
.green{
background-color:green;
color:white
}
```

```html
<table>
<tbody>
<tr id="1" class="blue"><td>blue</td></tr>   
<tr  class="blue"><td>blue</td></tr>         
<tr  class="blue"><td>blue</td></tr>   

<tr id="2" class="red"><td>red</td></tr>   
<tr  class="red"><td>red</td></tr>         

<tr id="3" class="green"><td>green</td></tr>   
<tr  class="green"><td>green</td></tr>         
<tr  class="green"><td>green</td></tr>  
<tr  class="green"><td>green</td></tr>         
<tr  class="green"><td>green</td></tr>  

</tbody>
</table>
```